# No Sound from Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: sound, 17.10

I am really banging my head on a brick wall on this, but no matter what I try I cannot get ANY sound from my speakers.

Tried the following

- sudo alsa force-reload
- sudo apt purge 'pulseaudio'

I then reinstalled pulseaudio and selected the analogue settings for built in speakers, but I am still not getting any sound! My sound card is a Creative Audio SoundBlaster Core 3D SB1570 SB AudigyFx. The card does work as I have tested it when running in Windows 10.

Further, I did a check and the OS does find the card!

Comment: Have you checked the BIOS/UEFI settings to make sure it isn't disabled? Are you dual booting with Windows? If so, try un-muting in Windows then reboot into Ubuntu and see if it is working
Upon research, it looks like this card may just have issues with Linux in general. Here is a forum post with mixed results:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/getting-a-soundblaster-audigy-fx-to-work-4175505881/

Comment: No I am dual booting from Ubuntu using Grub. So Ubuntu is always the default. Windows is not affecting this